# Download multiple files from BOX via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, box-api, box

I'm trying to download several files from BOX server via AJAX by using [their api](https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-download-a-file). So my script to download each file is like this:

```
var args = {
  url: url,
  headers: headers,        
  crossDomain: true,        
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
  error: function(data){
   //the server will return a redirect (it corresponds to error event)
   console.log(data);

   if (data.status == 200 && data.readyState == 4){                
       // so something with data.responseText           
   }   
   else{
       alert("The file is not downloadable.");
       return;                
   }
  }
};
$.ajax(args);
```

However, if I want to download 2 files, say A and B, and I want to use their contents for further computation after calling the AJAX download. Sometimes I got the error that A's (or/and B's) content is empty. I search around and figure out that's because of [ajax asynchronous](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options). Then what I tried to to is to set `async: false`, but then BOX returns both the queries are invalid.

So how should I do to make it work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use promises and then you can use [.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

However because these particular AJAX calls do not fire the success callback, I *think* you will need to [create your own](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/06/03/make-your-own-jquery-deferreds-and-promises/) - [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and then you can call `resolve()` on each one as each AJAX request fires the error callback but has a `data.status` of 200. Then you can use `.when()` and pass it your two deferreds.

Note: You will need jQuery >= 1.5

Okay, here is the code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SdYjP/));

```
var dfd1 = $.Deferred();
var dfd2 = $.Deferred();

$.when(dfd1.promise(), dfd2.promise()).done(function(){
    // both are done;
    alert('done!');
})

$.ajax({  
    url: "https://api.github.com",  
    type:'POST',  
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
        if(err.readyState === 4) {
            dfd1.resolve();
        }
    },
});  

$.ajax({  
    url: "https://api.github.com",  
    type:'POST',  
    error: function(err){
        if(err.readyState === 4) {
            dfd2.resolve();
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, let me try and see if it works :)

Comment: Hey @Loi.Luu, just seeing if you had any luck with this?